# Using setAttribute to toggle @click in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was wondering if there's any way to use setAttribute to toggle @click in VueJS.

```
setAttribute("@click", 'delete')
```

Whenever I do this I just get an exception.

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '@click' is not a valid attribute name
```

So, if that's not possible, can I do it any other way..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your login/condition ? when you want to add this attribute ?

Comment: @RishiRaut I'm using Fullcalendar. Need this to set a delete icon when rendering my event. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender

Comment: It is not possible, because the VueJS template is compiled at runtime and it is not possible to add `@click`, since it is not actually a HTML attribute, but one that is recognized by VueJS internally. This feels like an XY problem: what do you want to do?

Comment: @Terry Thanks for explaning! So I want to trigger a delete action when I click the icon, however I'm not sure how to do this when using eventRender in Fullcalendar.

Answer (score 0):

To further elabourate on my comment, it is not possible to directly modify the rendered HTML in that sense, because VueJS actually compiles the template at runtime and the `@click` attribute is actually parsed as a click event handler internally.

What you should do is to simply include the `@click` in the template itself, and then when the method is called, you can then add a guard clause in it that will not do anything, if a certain condition is not satisfied, i.e.

```
<!-- Template -->
<button @click="delete"></button>
```

...in your JS file:

```
methods: {
  delete() {
    // Guard clause
    if (condition) {
      return;
    }

    // Otherwise, proceed with deletion
  }
}
```

The `condition` will be part of the component data, which you can update dynamically depending on what kind of condition you want to guard against. The default component data will be `{ condition: false }`, and then you simply update `this.condition = true` when a certain criteria is met, i.e. when `eventRender` from FullCalendar is called/invoked.

---

Based on the script you've provided, you can add `hasCalendarRendered` into your component data:

```
data: () => ({
    hasCalenderRendered: false,
    // Rest of the component data
}),
```

And then in the `eventRender` method, you simply flip the boolean:

```
eventRender(event) {
  this.hasCalendarRendered = true;
}
```

Then in a delete method:

```
delete() {
  if (!this.hasCalendarRendered)
    return;

  // Rest of the delete logic
}
```

Comment: This is not possible for me, since I'm using eventRender in fullcalendar. I need to trigger it from inside a method called eventRender (if that makes any sense...)

Comment: @Someuser It is possible, but you need to share the code on how Fullcalendar is instantiated in your VueJS app. Right now we are shooting in the blank because you failed to provide a minimal, concrete and verifiable example. For example, where are you doing the `new Calendar(...)`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Pnm1hrnT 

Is it possible to use an eventListener?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this